Keyboard doesn't work correctly when booting the linux kernel with single mode from CFE bootloader using UART
I've been encountering a specific and weird bug that i honestly can't seem to find any solution for, i've been toying around with this blu ray player and found a uart port, i wire it to my pi pico that acts as a TTL-TO-USB converter for my computer and all is well, i manage to get into the CFE bootloader and am able to use my keyboard without any issues, i then tried getting a shell by booting into the linux kernel using the command
boot -elf -z flash0.kernel: 'root=/dev/romblock2 console=0,115200n8 BDVD_BOOT_AUTOSTART=y BAPP_OUT=/dev/console memcfg=384 single ro

and as expected the bootloader loads the kernel without any issues and i am indeed given a shell, but the problem is as i went to type anything, no letter was seemingly going through, that is until i pressed the numeric keys which were going through fine, i then pressed the function keys and noticed that F1 was being typed out as 11, F2 as 12, F3 as 13 and so on, another thing i noticed is when i pressed the arrow keys they would convert to A,B,C or D and finally noticed when i put caps lock on and pressed the letters ABCDEF, they would go through, i believe for some reason the shell is only accepting hex inputs which is confusing to say the least, provided here a screenshot of the issue:
Keyboard bug
I'm also using putty for uart communication, any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!
